# Evitar herencia de caracteres en Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

He implementado Bootstrap en mi sitio web por el asunto de la barra de navegación. Funciona bien pero me esta alterando las fuentes, las que en mi caso son de Google fonts, lo que favorece mi trabajo en SEO. Quisiera saber como evitar esto y hacer un seteo de las clases que necesito y las que no. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar el orden de los archivos css que estas implementando, por que si bootstrap lo estas llamando después de tu hoja de estilos te puede alterar los estilos propios

```
<!-- Asimilo que quizás tengas las importaciones asi  -->
<link href="assets/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<!-- La forma correcta  -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- De esta forma no debería alterar los estilos propios si estan debidamente declarados -->
```